# Display hundreds of polygons features on a Vector Layer with good performances

Tags: rendering, openlayers, openlayers-6

Since version 6.0.0, rendering has changed a lot in OpenLayers.
It was possible to optimize rendering performances using webGL but now, it seems to be only possible for Points or Tiles.

In my case, with default options, VectorSource / VectorLayer and >900 Polygon Features, the View becomes laggy and not very usable.

With version >6.0.0, is it possible to display many Polygon Features on a VectorLayer with good performances ?

**EDIT**

The styling is added with a constant object in the VectorLayer options:

```js
this.olLayer = new VectorLayer({
        style: Entity.featureStyle
      })
```

```js
class Entity {
  public static readonly featureStyle = new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#2196F3',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
    })
  })

  // ...
}
```

Comment: How are you styling the features?  You should be able to display many thousands of features before performance degrades significantly as long as the styling is efficient (i.e. using a style function with predefined or cached style objects and not consuming resources by repeatedly creating new style objects during rendering). 100000 polygons will be still slow, but 900 should not.

Comment: @Mike The features are styled by the `style` option of the VectorLayer and I don't use a function. I updated the question to show the code.

Comment: How complex are your geometries?  I get reasonable performance with your style, and with a combination of styles https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-c4e42 with 10000 simple polygons.  But increase the array to 100000 and and rendering does get noticeably slower.

Comment: Yes geometries are quite complex. I've applied simplification (`Geometry.simplify(200)`) but geometries are ugly when I zoom on the map. Is it possible to decrease the simplification tolerence automatically on the zoom ?

Comment: You could have both quality and simplified geometry as feature properties, and use those according to the rendering resolution.  In this exaggerated example https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-uyr3b the circular polygons are very simplified until zoom 5, less simplified until zoom 10, then best quality.

Comment: That is finally what I've done and yes, it works much better !